# Can we make the site look nicer by having a *weekly featured picture* like at Photography?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Photography Stack Exchange has a [weekly featured picture](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured-photo). This makes the site look nicer. Could we do the same with a travel-related photo each week? Or is this not possible as long as we are in beta?

Comment: I wouldn't hold my breath until we are out of beta. SE devs are not likely to spend time on a unique feature like this until the site graduates, especially when it's not critical to the site's functioning. It's a good idea, nevertheless -- just not likely to be realized at this stage.

Comment: @mindcorrosive: That's no reason to leave all post-beta plans unplanned.

Comment: @mindcorrosive if they've already implemented it for Photography, it shouldn't be much work to implement it for travel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not? That would be a nice way for all the keen photographers who are members of this forum to share their travel pictures!